# errors.ts:42 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

getting one error on my logging component can't solve it!

[Here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZV8w.png)

[And i have the following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJDnK.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevent code/error as plain text. Links can break over time, and copying from images isn't as easy as from text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check spelling. Your reference is `#loginForm="ngForm"`, but you are using `!logInForm.form.valid`.

Comment: Thanks alot, didn't saw that!